# How can I install Ubuntu's Ambiance theme in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: icons, themes, 20.04, ambiance

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 last week but I hate the default Yaru theme. I just love the old Ubuntu Ambiance theme and the Ubuntu's old icon pack.

How do I install the old Ambiance theme and icon pack?

Answer (score 6):

You can install the `light-themes` package from the [universe repo](https://askubuntu.com/q/148638/480481) to get the Ambiance and Radiance themes. To do that, run the following command in Terminal

```
sudo apt install light-themes
```

For the icons, the Humanity icon theme should be installed by default. If it's not for some reason, install it by running

```
sudo apt install humanity-icon-theme
```

Then you can install (GNOME) Tweaks by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

and use it to switch to your preferred theme.